# What's the difference between a double? and a double and why can't I implicitly convert them?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Visual studio is yelling at me, in the database it is a float, and in my class it is a double. Why can't I assign it and why does it think it's a 'double?' ?

LINE THREE BELOW

```
    Confirmation confirm = new Confirmation();

    confirm.order = theOrder;

    confirm.totalPrice = theOrder.BillingAmount;
```

HERE IS Confirmation DEF

```
    public class Confirmation
    {
        public Order order;

        public List<OrderItem> allProducts;

        public double totalPrice;
    }
```

HERE IS BillingAmount DEF from code I think generated from .dbml draggy-droppy...

```
[Column(Storage="_BillingAmount", DbType="Float")]
        public System.Nullable<double> BillingAmount
        {
            get
            {
                return this._BillingAmount;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._BillingAmount != value))
                {
                    this.OnBillingAmountChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._BillingAmount = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("BillingAmount");
                    this.OnBillingAmountChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is the code, I noticed the Nullable thing and then I saw the dudes comment below, is there a good way to convert or should I be making it a decimal? inside my class?

Answer (score 7):

In the db, if your column is nullable, this is represented in C# as `Nullable<double>`.  double, being a value type, can not be null...but in db terms this is perfectly legal.  That's why .Net has the `Nullable<T>` type.  You can assign its value to a double by doing any of the following

```
double d = nullableDouble ?? 0;
double d = (nullableDouble.HasValue) ? nullableDouble.Value : 0;
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

`double?` is shorthand for `Nullable<double>`.  It's a completely different type.  My recollection is that you *can* implicitly convert between them, but only in one direction (from `double` to `double?`).  The other direction doesn't make sense, because in the case where the `double?` is null, no conversion would exist.  The reason the database code uses a nullable double is because, in the database, the value could possibly be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

A double? is a nullable version of a double that can represent an "unknown" value, as well as a definitive double.  The difference between a double and a float is that a double has twice the precision and range that a float has.

So you should be able to implicitly convert any float into a double, but not the other way around, Just like you can convert any short integer ( -32,768 to +32769)  into a long ( - 2 Billion to + 2 billion), bit not the other way around.

EDIT:
  So you can also implicitly convert a double into a nullable double (double?)  but not the other way around (it might be null).

But you can still convert a nullable double ***Explicitly***.  if it has a definite value, then you can convert it by casting it, or by accessing the "Value" property of the double?

```
   double? nulbleDbl = 123.456;
   double?   nullDbl = null;
   double x = nulbleDbl.Value;  //works just fine
   double y = nullDbl.Value;  // fails with convert error or cast error
   bool isOk = nullDbl.HasValue;  // returns false
```

Comment: so should I make it a nullable one in my other object I want to use it in or is there a good way to convert?

Comment: @Ryan, if it's a nullable in one, and ity has a definite value, then you can EXPLICITLY conver it by casting it, or by accessing the "Value" property of the double?

Answer (score 1):

The way to convert a double? to a double is:

```
double? nullDouble = null;
double normaDouble = nullDouble ?? 0; 
  // where 0 is the default value used if nullDouble is null
```

this is the same as:

```
normalDouble = (nullDouble.HasValue) ? nullDouble.Value : 0;
```

or 
    normalDouble = (nullDouble != null) ? nullDouble.Value : 0;

Comment: omg... that '??' what does that do, if it is what I think it is you have made me very happy (and feel powerful)

Comment: It's the null coalescing operator. It means "use the left hand side, unless it is null, in which case, use the right hand side".  The type coercion rules are a bit complicated; see the specification if you need details.

Answer (score 0):

Your column in the DB must be Allowing Nulls, because a double? was generated.  So if it can be null, it means it is possible that it does not get a value from your program.  So maybe  you should choose between double? or double, but to work with that everywhere (and maybe not allowing nulls in the DB).